# How to install and setup docker to use folder outside boot?

Tags: docker, storage, boot-partition

I want to use docker to run a couple of dockerized 'apps/services' from time to time on my laptop. I have a boot partition with 100 gb (50gb occupied) and a 900 gb home folder setup via fstab and ext4.

I installed docker on ubuntu 18.04 using

```
sudo apt install docker.io
```

And spun up a container using the standard command(?).
But things escalated quickly as my workload involves tons of image data and I ran out of space on my boot partition very fast. My question is:

How to setup docker, so that it only uses the minimal space on the boot partition and preferably keeps all containers, app data, temp files, etc in a specific folder in the home directory, e.g. 'home/user/data/docker'?

Bonus question: Is there a good docker management GUI application? I like the way I can setup docker containers on openmediavault, but its not an option here.

Answer (score 0):

The data handled by containerized apps can be in bind-mounted volumes that map any file/directory on your disk to file/directories in the container file space:

```
docker run --volume /path/in/host:/path/in/container ...
```

Moving the Docker infrastructure itself (`/var/lib/docker`) is likely complicated, but you can try to set up a link from `/var/lib/docker` to some other place. But a well managed Docker isn't that big (2.4GB for me with a dozen different base OS images). If you use it right, there is a lot of file space sharing between the images.